# Is there a way to make hibernate throw an exception for an unmapped class?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Hibernate's use of implicit polymorphism means that when you have a query (Criteria in my case) explicitly associated with a class for which there is no hibernate mapping, it fails silently (returns an empty list - in fact it doesn't even perform the query as it doesn't know what the class maps to in the database).

I'm curious if there's a configuration setting that makes this failure more verbose as for a large project it isn't always straightforward to verify that all queries that are associated with a class have a mapping defined in the hibernate configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so. It is apparently designed this way to support implicit polymorphism (see http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1665 ).

However, to me it looks a lot more like a bug than anything else... :-)

Comment: indeed, the compiler analogy would suggest an unresolved class exception should be thrown